# The use of "in" or "on" in context

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please which preposition is correct to use in the following sentence.

> We are going to work the shoulders **in**/**on** the next workout.

I am leaning towards *in*, but not 100℅ sure if it is correct, if it is not, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **in** sounds sounds more natural in this context; it implies that working the shoulders is a component of the next workout and is loosely synonymous with many alternative words which may be used in this phrase, for example:

> We are going to work the shoulders **in** the next workout.

> We are going to work the shoulders **as part of** the next workout.

> We are going to work the shoulders **during** the next workout.

Whereas, the use of **on** in the same phrase focuses more on the time of the next workout and seems to evoke a similar meaning to:

> We are going to work the shoulders **next time**.

> We are going to work the shoulders **on the next occasion**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your sentence is grammatically incorrect and needs a "the":

> We are going to work the shoulders in/on **the** next workout.

In your example **both are correct**.

As an English speaker, though, I think *in* sounds nicer.

Comment: This is one of those cases where multiple prepositions would work. In addition to _in_ or _on_, I think we could use _with_ or _for_, too – and most certainly _during_.

Comment: **At** also works.  I think this answer could be improved if you explained the difference in nuance (if any) between the various preposition options.